# ES6 react state change doesn't affect render inline if clause

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have this subcomponent which renders a "report bugg" button and should display the report bugg form when it is being pressed.
e.g : button pressed -> state update to report_toggle = true

As seen in this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReportBox from './ReportBox';

class ReportBugButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.toggleReportBox = this.toggleReportBox.bind(this);
    this.reportSubmit = this.reportSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      report_toggle: true
    }
  }
  toggleReportBox(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.state.report_toggle ? this.state.report_toggle = false : this.state.report_toggle = true;
    console.log("State ist: ", this.state.report_toggle);
  }
  reportSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();

  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <a href="#" onClick={this.toggleReportBox} className="report-button tooltip" title="Report a bug"><i className="fa fa-bug"></i></a>
        { this.state.report_toggle ? <ReportBox toggleReport={this.toggleReportBox} submitReport={this.reportSubmit} /> : '' }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ReportBugButton;
```

When the Report Button is clicked the console log perfectly shows that the state is being updated since it always changes between "State is: true" and "State is: false".

Unfortunately the inline if in the render method doesn't seem to care much since it doesn't display the component if it the state is true.

If I set the state true by default it is being displayed , but not being hidden when its set to false by clicking.

Any ideas ? ... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are changing state the wrong way. You should **NEVER** modify the state variable directly.

Use [`this.setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate).

e.g

```
   this.setState({ report_toggle: !this.state.report_toggle });
```

Only when you call this function, is the `render` function triggered and re-rendering is done (only if some state variables changed).

Comment: You are right, weirdly enough this has been my first approach since i never did the direct modification. Unfortunately the issue was babelify breaking down on my last tries. Thank you anyhow :)

Comment: @noa-dev You can attach `babel-loader` to `Webpack` to make things easier.

Comment: @noa-dev You can accept the answer if this works for you.